# VS2008 Express no longer opens projects after VS2010 express Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

So I installed the new april release of the VS2010 express for windows phone 7 and now VS2008 express C# no longer opens .csproj files. I'm at a loss as to why this is as I've not changed anything in the files themselves. I'm currently uninstalling windows phone 7 in the hopes that I will be able to open my files again. I have a feeling though I'm going to need to uninstall 2008 as well and the reinstall it to get everything to work.

In the future how should I install 2010 express for win 7 phone to prevent it from interfering with 2008 express?

Comment: What happens when you try and open the project?

Comment: Project type not supported by this installation.

Comment: I think if you open a project/solution in 2010, and save it, even if you changed nothing, you won't be able to open it in 2008.

Comment: I didn't open it in 2008. So I'm not sure if that is it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can change file associations without reinstalling apps. If you open Visual Studio 2008, go Tools->Options, there should be a button somewhere to "Restore file associations".

Comment: I uninstalled 2008 and 2010, and whipped the registry and I was able to then reinstall Visual Studio 2008 and the XNA game studios. I can now open all of my old projects. Still makes me wonder what went wrong.